# How to solve R Markdown (Knit) "'closure' is not subsettable"?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to use RMarkdown (Knit) for the first time to produce pdf. The default file (File > New File > R Markdown) works well, it shows the generated pdf when compiled. For example, the following code runs,

````
```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

However, if I just change cars with "myData," it does not compile and shows,

```
Error in object[[i]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> summary -> summary.default
Execution halted
```

I have "myData" loaded in the global-environment and can do other operations in original R script. Can someone please provide some guideline. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I think your data `myData` is not desired for `summary()`. Try `print(myData)` instead of `summary(myData)`and you will get some results in your PDF.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but it didn't work. Summary() stopped the compilation, print() prints a pdf but does not print the myData summary. It prints couple of functions, meta data etc. Thank you.

Comment: well, `knit` won't use the global environment by default so that's prbly your main problem here.

Comment: Well, then how can I configure knitr to use global variables, if you may shade some lights on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running an Rmarkdown file starts a new R session.

Within the new session, you can load the data.frames that are stored in the `data` package, but other datasets must be loaded from within the Rmarkdown document.

To get myData to show up in your Rmarkdown document,

1. save the file somewhere with `save` in your current R session
2. then in your Rmarkdown document, use `load` to open up the data set

So, in your current R session:

```
save(myData, file="<path>/myData.Rdata")
```

and in your Rmarkdown file:

````
```{r myDataSummary}
load("<path>/myData.Rdata")
summary(myData)
```
````

If your data is stored as a text file, and you don't wish to store a separate .R file, use `read.csv` or friend directly within your Rmarkdown file.

````
```{r myDataSummary}
myData <- read.csv("<path>/myCSV.csv")
summary(myData)
```
````

Comment: Thank you. That's the solution. Thanks for your explanation too, that was more important. I have added my solution here too.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error you get when you try to subset (= via `x[i]`) a *function*. Since this error is caused by `summary(cars)` in your code, we may surmise that the `cars` object refers to a function in the scope in which the document is knit.

You probably forgot to load your data, or you have a function with the same name defined in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

As @Imo explained, the basic problem is the new session. So, the answer would be adding the script in the rMarkdown. However, it will create few more hiccups. Here is how I handled few of them,

````
```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
source(file = "C:\\Path\\to\\my\\file.R")
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=12, fig.height=8, fig.path='Figs/',
                      echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
```
````