# multiple linear regression function

Tags: r

I just tries to write a function of multiple linear regression in R. But there is an error when I want to make read data function put into one chunk. There is an error:
df$X1: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable calls
This error would not happen when I just run this chunk, only appear when I knit.

````
   ```{r, warning=FALSE, message = FALSE}
#Create the function of multiple linear regression
MLG = function (x,y, FileName) {
  df = read.csv(FileName, fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM", header = TRUE)

  summary(df)
  #create the model
  lm = lm (x~y, df)
  #call lm to see result
  lm
  #get the result of model
  summary(lm)
  #plot the result of model to analysis the outliers
  par(mfrow = c(2,2))
  plot(lm)
}
MLG(FileName = "1.5.csv", x = df$X1, y= df$X3 + df$X4 + df$X5 + df$X6 + df$X7)

```
````

This is my code.

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide a subset of your data so that this problem is reproducible on other people's machines. Thanks :)

Comment: This almost certainly means you have not initialized/ loaded data explicitly into a variable df inside your knit document. It does not matter when you run the function separately because there is a df in your current session. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943824/how-to-solve-r-markdown-knit-closure-is-not-subsettable

Comment: `df` is an R function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass `df$X1` to a function before `df` is created. The easy way would be to just pass a formula to your function (it won't look for the objects it refers to until the `lm` call.

```
MLG = function (formula, FileName) {
  df = read.csv(FileName, fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM", header = TRUE)

  summary(df)
  #create the model
  lm = lm (formula, df)
  #call lm to see result
  lm
  #get the result of model
  summary(lm)
  #plot the result of model to analysis the outliers
  par(mfrow = c(2,2))
  plot(lm)
}
MLG(FileName = "1.5.csv", formula = X1 ~ X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7)
```

This also gives you the ability to add interaction terms, transformations, etc.

As a side-note, I'd recommend you use the ubiquitous convention that `y` is your response and `x` is your predictor(s). Switching them will cause confusion.